# Django: FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'username' into field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am putting up a website. I have two apps in my website- 'accounts' and 'articles'. I am trying to create a User view which when searched by username returns all articles authored by that particular user.
The models are:

articles.models.py

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    content = models.TextField()
    uploads = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='uploads/')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='articles')
    clappers = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="claps", blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    is_anonymous = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = get_unique_slug(self.id, self.title, Article.objects)
        return super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


def get_unique_slug(id, title, obj):
    slug = slugify(title.replace('ı', 'i'))
    unique_slug = slug
    counter = 1
    while obj.filter(slug=unique_slug).exists():
        if(obj.filter(slug=unique_slug).values('id')[0]['id'] == id):
            break
        unique_slug = '{}-{}'.format(slug, counter)
        counter += 1
    return unique_slug
```

The accounts.models.py file:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    avatar = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=120, unique=True)

    def get_username(self):
        return self.username

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = get_unique_slug(self.id, self.username, User.objects)
        return super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


def get_unique_slug(id, title, obj):
    slug = slugify(title.replace('ı', 'i'))
    unique_slug = slug
    counter = 1
    while obj.filter(slug=unique_slug).exists():
        if(obj.filter(slug=unique_slug).values('id')[0]['id'] == id):
            break
        unique_slug = '{}-{}'.format(slug, counter)
        counter += 1
    return unique_slug
```

Here is my accounts.articles.py file:

```
class UserAPIView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsUserOrReadOnly]
    lookup_field = 'username'

    def get_queryset(self):
        author = self.kwargs.get("username")
        print(author)
        # double __
        return Article.objects.filter(author__username=author).order_by("-created_at")
```

and the urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    path('registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    path('user/<str:username>/', UserAPIView.as_view(), name='account-view')
]
```

What could be the problem? And what's the solution?

EDIT: Error Log:

```
Internal Server Error: /api/auth/user/admin12/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py", line 252, in get
    return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 54, in retrieve
    instance = self.get_object()
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py", line 96, in get_object
    obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, **filter_kwargs)
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py", line 19, in get_object_or_404
    return _get_object_or_404(queryset, *filter_args, **filter_kwargs)
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 76, in get_object_or_404
    return queryset.get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 404, in get
    clone = self._chain() if self.query.combinator else self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 904, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 923, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1350, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1377, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1250, in build_filter
    lookups, parts, reffed_expression = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1087, in solve_lookup_type
    _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1482, in names_to_path
    raise FieldError("Cannot resolve keyword '%s' into field. "
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'username' into field. Choices are: author, author_id, clappers, content, created_at, id, is_anonymous, slug, title, updated_at, uploads
```

EDIT2:
Upon making the following changes, the API seems to be working but returns a 404 even though I have an instance of the User model which has an article.

```
class UserAPIView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsUserOrReadOnly]
    lookup_field = 'author'

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        author = self.kwargs.get('author')
        print(author)
        # double __
        return Article.objects.filter(author__username=author).order_by("-created_at")
```

urls.py

```
path('user/<str:author>/', UserAPIView.as_view(), name='account-view')
```

Comment: Can you please show your error log? It's much harder to tell your problem if we don't know where is the error raised.

Comment: @crimsonpython24 I have added the error log

Comment: shouldn't you using be `ArticleSerializer` instead of `UserSerializer`?

Comment: @neferpitou I changed it to ArticleSerializer, gives the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `view` you are using wrong serializer.

```
class UserAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsUserOrReadOnly]

    def get_queryset(self):
        author = self.kwargs.get('username')
        print(author)
        # double __
        return Article.objects.filter(author__username=author).order_by("-created_at")
```

Create a `ArticleSerializer` and replace it with `UserSerializer` and it should be fine.
Also remove the lookup field.

EDIT: Use either `generics.ListAPIView` or `viewsets.ModelViewSet`

Comment: Somehow it leaves the same error even after changing to ArticleSerializer

Comment: check the edit i have removed the `lookup` field. Just one thing how are passing the `username`? Does it check for logged in user?

Comment: Nope. It returns the view depending on the URL passed. When the username extension is passed with the URL : user/username/, I want it to return articles by that particular author.

Comment: or `self.kwargs.get('username')` should also work; without passing `**kwargs`

Comment: Really appreciate your help. Some progress, I've made a second edit to my question. The API seems to be working however it returns a 404 even though there is a user instance which is associated with an article. I tried all the other methods you suggested, the edit I made is the only edit that worked.

Comment: before return statement, try to print the result: `qs = Article.objects.filter(author__username=author).order_by("-created_at")` and then `print(qs)` and check if it is actually returning anything or not.

Comment: <QuerySet [<Article: Article object (1)>]> So, by this I assume there is an Article Object which is being found for that particular author?

Comment: Yes, on the next line `return qs`; and your view should be fine

Comment: doing that gives me the response {"detail": "Not Found"}

Comment: Okay. I changed it to a viewset and it worked. I don't know what was the problem with the earlier code though.

Comment: now that you mentioned it `ListAPIView` will return list of objects; `Retrieve` is for getting specific object. My bad i didn't pay attention to it and `ModelViewSet` will also work fine with it :)

Answer (score -1):

Okay. I didn't know why my edit didn't work. When I tried to print the queryset returned it did return an Article object. However, I couldn't get a JSON response of the object.

I tried changing it to a Viewset, and it worked.

```
class UserAPIView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsUserOrReadOnly]
    lookup_field = 'author'

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        author = self.kwargs.get('author')
        print(author)
        # double __
        qs = Article.objects.filter(
            author__username=author).order_by("-created_at")
        return qs
```